# How to get name, latitude and longitude information from an external javascript file embedded inside script tag?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

I need to scrape name, latitude & longitude of list of restaurants from https://food.grab.com/ph/en/restaurants and save them to a csv. This is 'load more' type website: 8 more restaurants will be added in the search results for every lick on 'load more' button.

When you inspect element, you have a body tag which contains a div followed by a list of script tags. The below code starts from second script tag.

```
<script async="" id="__NEXT_PAGE__/restaurants" src="/_next/static/~k5VPZk5KBtLKJOP7fLbR/pages/restaurants.js"></script>

<script async="" id="__NEXT_PAGE__/_app" src="/_next/static/~k5VPZk5KBtLKJOP7fLbR/pages/_app.js"></script>

<script async="" src="/_next/static/chunks/146.5cc25d7743407960833f.js"></script>

<script src="/_next/static/runtime/webpack-562f11f96da3918c3d37.js" async=""></script>

<script src="/_next/static/chunks/styles.4fc2149595e9293ccd52.js" async=""></script>
```

For restaurants loaded after clicking 'load more', the latitude/longitude information seems to be stored in external javascript file stored in script tag with id="**NEXT_PAGE**/restaurants" (or the other external js files right below).

I am new to Javascript. I went through the first js file but unable to figure out how to get the required info. I couldn't find any variables with restaurant names or locations mentioned explicitly. Also skimmed through other js files but can't find anything. Not sure if I should look for script tags in the header instead. Can someone answer this?

Answer (score 3):

It has nothing to do with JavaScript files.

JavaScript receives relevant information by sending http requests to the server

These requests are visible

You must repeat the same requests with Python

in [devtools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/) go to network tab, check all request. when you click on load more btn a request sent to `https://portal.grab.com/foodweb/v2/search`

see response in response section is:

```
{"searchResult":{"searchID":"910af096fe304265a0f3d4a3e8b5e2d8","totalCount":515,"searchMerchants":[{"id":"2-C2MFREUZN6WKLN","address":{"name":"Wai Ying Fastfood - Binondo [Available for LONG-DISTANCE DELIVERY]"},"latlng":{"latitude":14.602068853150598,"longitude":120.97598854230432},"estimatedDeliveryTime":30,"merchantBrief":{"description":"Prices are all VAT inclusive. Prices may also vary or be subject to change by the merchant.","cuisine":["Asian","Noodles","Quick Bites"],"photoHref":"https://d1sag4ddilekf6.azureedge.net/compressed/merchants/2-C2MFREUZN6WKLN/hero/12a517f18aed4fc7ac9d10ef754193fa_1617944281957721088.jpeg","isIntegrated":true,"openHours":{"open":true,"displayedHours":"08:00-20:00","sun":"08:00-20:00","mon":"08:00-20:00","tue":"08:00-20:00","wed":"08:00-20:00","thu":"08:00-20:00","fri":"08:00-20:00","sat":"08:00-....
```

get restaurant_id from this response, each restaurant_id stored with `id` key

then when you click on one restaurants a request sent to `https://portal.grab.com/foodweb/v2/merchants/2-CYKCVZNZJTDFLE?latlng=14.5995,120.9842`

where `2-CYKCVZNZJTDFLE` is ‍`restaurant_id‍`

and response is :

```
{
  "merchant": {
    "ID": "2-CYKCVZNZJTDFLE",
    "latlng": {
      "latitude": 14.6094796,
      "longitude": 120.992802
    },
    "name": "Yellow Cab Pizza - Espana [Available for LONG-DISTANCE DELIVERY]",
   ....
    "businessType": "FOOD",
  },
  "promotions": null
}
```

you can get `latitude` and `longitude` from here

make the `https://portal.grab.com/foodweb/v2/search` request and `https://portal.grab.com/foodweb/v2/merchants/{id}` with python, but insure all of the http headers must be same with http headers that in the [chrome dev tools](https://mkyong.com/computer-tips/how-to-view-http-headers-in-google-chrome/)

Comment: I know how to get lat/long info from json object. Just let me know how to get and store 'response' in response section into a variable, so that I can save it as json file. I should be able to do this for multiple pages that load after clicking 'load more'.

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot. But there is one last thing now. Say I click 'load more' 3 times using selenium or manually. Each search request's response can be seen in response section of network tab. Now how do I store each response object in a variable like say 'page'? Or how can I locate it using selenium (by using findElement() method)? Since the response is json objects here, I can save them and do my required work. Thanks.