# How to pass Request Headers into requests.get(url, headers = headers) in proper format?

Tags: google-chrome, web-scraping, http-headers, request-headers

Below are the request headers I copied from chrome. How do I pass these values to response = requests.get(url, headers = headers) so that I don't get any error. Should all the keys and values be made strings by enclosing within '' ?

:authority: portal.grab.com

:method: POST

:path: /foodweb/v2/search

:scheme: https

accept: application/json, text/plain, */*

accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br

accept-language: en

content-length: 87

content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

origin: https://food.grab.com

referer: https://food.grab.com/

sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="95", "Chromium";v="95", ";Not A Brand";v="99"

sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0

sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"

sec-fetch-dest: empty

sec-fetch-mode: cors

sec-fetch-site: same-site

user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36

x-country-code: PH

x-gfc-country: PH

x-grab-web-app-version: ~k5VPZk5KBtLKJOP7fLbR

x-recaptcha-token: 03AGdBq24a8dFVYhN75ZFSZR6MSzf8anLJEc-c6xCFkUYi87f5FQLlYV8NeHspOYwqJYS1ypTDvpPVU4FG6NbvkwbwHgHCxAOaiHi8sLtnraXL78xszl-HgySw_yBGCadmL4I9TmnDL8HITA4ug4FZ-tITOWIE9AI1L2OWAgFJC25r663aHtF16pJGLJovE4D1IVm2NziSUhWNdlv9aSxym4s1dGhM9YTu0w2FNCfiHqLURKs-sk4GLQ-O1Xv2xuTRuvBiDxXZYisKKt0nnoMpov5CPmwzFVaQGFXVk5xLz05bsbsdN7gf4DcoGD8i1yM3vbNMld-gqgDJ6DhLX3IY6NxJ_2QdH-dQctu4OCB9oPUursOAFs6ph8Xqf_kL3XQLzdO2qRMhU9wVlmAocV8lm8DTF0Urxp1JkRY6X7SeKDeQsX0KX2vO3ZFFjfYb19Gqpts5CQCGJO5j

Answer (score 2):

There is an example how to format headers in Python requests documentation: [Custom Headers](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) so in your case it should looks like this:

```py
headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, /',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en',
    'content-length': '87',
    'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'origin': 'https://food.grab.com',
    'referer': 'https://food.grab.com/',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="95", "Chromium";v="95", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36',
    'x-country-code': 'PH',
    'x-gfc-country': 'PH',
    'x-grab-web-app-version': '~k5VPZk5KBtLKJOP7fLbR',
    'x-recaptcha-token': '03AGdBq24a8dFVYhN75ZFSZR6MSzf8anLJEc-c6xCFkUYi87f5FQLlYV8NeHspOYwqJYS1ypTDvpPVU4FG6NbvkwbwHgHCxAOaiHi8sLtnraXL78xszl-HgySw_yBGCadmL4I9TmnDL8HITA4ug4FZ-tITOWIE9AI1L2OWAgFJC25r663aHtF16pJGLJovE4D1IVm2NziSUhWNdlv9aSxym4s1dGhM9YTu0w2FNCfiHqLURKs-sk4GLQ-O1Xv2xuTRuvBiDxXZYisKKt0nnoMpov5CPmwzFVaQGFXVk5xLz05bsbsdN7gf4DcoGD8i1yM3vbNMld-gqgDJ6DhLX3IY6NxJ_2QdH-dQctu4OCB9oPUursOAFs6ph8Xqf_kL3XQLzdO2qRMhU9wVlmAocV8lm8DTF0Urxp1JkRY6X7SeKDeQsX0KX2vO3ZFFjfYb19Gqpts5CQCGJO5j'
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error like this: ValueError: Invalid header name b':authority'

Comment: Do I just need to pass headers section from copied fetch to response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)?

Comment: Sorry I edited answer once again, described way to get headers is for response headers not request. You need to remove headers that starts with a colon.

Comment: Yes, just do this like it's described in `Custom Headers` linked in answer.

Comment: I removed key-value pairs that start with colon from request headers as you suggested. When I make request with this, it's taking forever to respond. See my previous question for context. Please help me if you can there too. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69838096/how-to-get-name-latitude-and-longitude-information-from-an-external-javascript

Comment: Sorry I have some problems with your site, it has some protection. I don't know if I would be able to help, but I will let you know if I do something.

Comment: Site you want to scrap uses `Google Invisible reCAPTCHA` so you probably need some paid service to get `x-recaptcha-token` value. Maybe there are other ways but I don't know about them.

Comment: I had a gut feeling that this has something to do with recaptcha. Thanks for confirming this. The other way is just going to network tab and copy-pasting the content under response sub-tab.

Comment: response = requests.get( 'portal.grab.com/foodweb/v2/search', headers = headers) ....When I use this it should return json/text corresponding to a page that loads after first click on 'load more' button. Header has POST request for this. Now if I want to get response object for further next page, is it fine if I use response = get(...) again ? In the request headers, only recaptcha is different for page 2 and 3...everything else is same. My question is how would the response object return two different pages with same url and headers. (Asking since you seem to be good at this. Thanks).

Comment: If header has POST in it you should use `requests.post(...)` every time. Different response with same url and headers may be due to wrong method (POST instead of GET etc.). Maybe it would be better for you to create new question to not spam here or go to chat.

Comment: @RPM Not all of it may be necessary
You have to test
Send them all first
Then delete them one by one and see if the received answers are still the same as before
They are generally sensitive to cookie and referral keys